# How can I access Ubuntu Server using MySQL Workbench and FileZilla?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I access Ubuntu Server using MySQL Workbench and FileZilla so that I can work on database and files from local Windows PC?

Comment: Are you sure the mysql server is running on the remote end? Does `# /etc/init.d/mysql status` return anything? Have you attempted a port scan against the remote machine to ensure that port 3306 is indeed open?

Comment: Just tried: SERVICE MYSQL STATUS and returned: MYSQL START/RUNNING, PROCESS 1416. Not sure what it means..

Comment: It means that it is up and running. You are all good. Please check the answer that kmassada has given to you.

Comment: Just tried a few things, but have to do everything from start to the end. I can connect to database on server PC using MySQL Workbench, but not from Win PC. Wll get back to you later, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

For filezilla, you need to setup an FTP server. https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html It will allow you to connect to your instance by using port 21. IP:21. But warning, FTP alone can be a security issue, especially if this server is accessible by external IP.

As for MySQL Workbench http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-new-server-instance-wizard.html It looks like it relies on ssh connection. So you'll need to setup an ssh server on that machine as well. https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html I think you might need to run " /etc/init.d/mysql status" like the first contributor mentioned. SSH might not be enough.

I don't know if mysql is already setup on that server but take a look at this as well
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/mysql.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, I haven't tried Linux before, so it takes me some time to understand what is what, thanks :)