# MySql - can i make a new connection in windows calling a linux ip address

Tags: mysql, connection, database, mysql-workbench

So trying to figure out if i can use workbench in windows 2008 server and ask it to connect to a linux machine over my network.

the reason behind this is my frontend application is in windows however the database is stored over at a linux machine and when changes are being made it needs to be made in the linux machine. is there anyway i can call the database which is located in linux.

I tried creating a new connection and in the IP address section i have added 192.168.1.XX which is my IP address. it says failed to connect to MySql at 192.168.1.XX:3306 with user root.

plz help me

Comment: In principle, the Windows machine should be able to connect to the Mysql server. Can you `ping` the Linux machine? Can you do `telnet 192.168.1.XX 3306`? If you get gibberish, it's OK. If you get something like "Connection refused", the Linux machine is not reachable from the Windows machine, or MySql is running on a non-default port, or does not allow access from the network.

Comment: BTW does this answer your question perhaps? http://askubuntu.com/questions/183245/how-can-i-access-ubuntu-server-using-mysql-workbench-and-filezilla?rq=1

Comment: As you say that the front end application is connected from Windows PC to Linux destination, have a look in through the config. Is your user root has a password? Were you able to connect mysql using the Linux PC itself?

Comment: thanks for the reply...so i tried telnet, it didnt connect hence i am assuming that the port is not open. I used sudo ufw allow 3306 in the terminal to add the port. how do i know this has worked...

in the mean time i am also assuming that i now need to create a new user with all rights. so i tried in terminal 
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
i get an error saying create: command not found. Plz help

Comment: also just to add i can ping the machine on both ends...but telnet doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, connect your windows app to MySQL on Linux - with MySQL ODBC driver.
I assume that you have one already installed.

What may be the problem here is granting access to the database from your Windows server.

Assuming that you have no network connection problem as such - as recommended in comments, you may try first to check telnet your_mysql_server_ip 3306, to see if you can access MySQL listening (or not) on your Linux system.
You can also check with netstat on the Linux server if the port 3306 is open and anything is listening on it at all.
If not - it may happen that your MySQL isn't configured to use network connections (it may work only locally, with sockets)

But assuming  that it's not network connection issue...

First of all I wouldn't really use root account, or any administrative MySQL account with too many permissions. Let's say I'm a bit paranoid with access settings.

Create a dedicated user for your particular database, with only necessary permissions granted for the access. To do that you will need to use "grant" command (this manual may help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

So you need something like that, for example (with probably waaay to broad privileges - I would change that "all" to whatever you need, ie.: "select,insert,update" - find more in the manual)

grant all privileges on your_db.* to your_user@your_windows_host identified by "the_password";

Technically you should actuall use "create user" command first - but "grant" will get this sorted for you as a part of its own task.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply...so i tried telnet, it didnt connect hence i am assuming that the port is not open. I used sudo ufw allow 3306 in the terminal to add the port. how do i know this has worked... in the mean time i am also assuming that i now need to create a new user with all rights. so i tried in terminal CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; i get an error saying create: command not found. Plz help –

Comment: That's MySQL command, not Unix. So you have first to connect with MySQL client - locally on your server, where you have proper permissions.

Comment: To test the port locally on the server you can also use telnet command, but you can also use netstat as mentioned earlier, to see if your MySQL is listening on that port on your server. You may also want to check your MySQL configuration to make sure it's configured to listen on the network port - as also mentioned earlier.